# how loadModel and modified field in another controller Cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have two tables, cars and locations; I want loadModel Car in `LocationsController` and I want, when I add location, for it to automatically status column in Cars table registers unavailable into locationsController:

```
    public function add($car_id) {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Location->create();
            if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                App::import('model','Car');
            $this->Car->write('Car.status', 'unavailable');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
         $users = $this->Location->User->find('list');
        $agencies = $this->Location->Agency->find('list');
        /*$cars = $this->Location->Car->find('list');*/
        $this->set(compact('agencies'));
        $this->set('car_id', $car_id);



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this lines

```
App::import('model','Car');
$this->Car->write('Car.status', 'unavailable');
```

Following code you have to write

```
 if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been saved.'));



             $this->loadModel("Car");
             $this->Car->id=$car_id;
             $this->Car->saveField("status","unavailable");

            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
```

[Check Manual here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false).